# what is "" echo $PWD | sed 's?.*users/[^/]\+/??' ""

Tags: sed

what is

```
echo $PWD | sed 's?.*users/[^/]\+/??'
```

Here PWD is path :

```
/proj/SAM1/users/ssudi/SAm/VELOCE/ML3P8/trunk
```

what exactly `sed` command is doing here and how `s?.*users/[^/]\+/??` this will work ?

Answer (score 2):

`s?.*users/[^/]\+/??` breaks down as follows:

- `s` is the command of **substitution**
- `?` (all three of them) are expression **separators** (so the above might look like this as well: `s@.*users/[^/]\+/@@`). The general form is this: `s/<match pattern>/<replacement>/<modifiers>`. In this case there are no modifiers and no replacement in this substitution, so whatever is found by the first pattern will be removed from the stream.
- `.*users/[^/]\+/` is the search pattern and means:

  - `.*`whatever precedes `users/`
  - `[^/]\+/` followed by something that's not `\` (at least one such thing, possibly more) and these followed by one `/`.

  So it's targeting a string in a path that begins with `users` and is followed by one subfolder, eg. `/subfolder/`.

And thus what's left is this:

```
SAm/VELOCE/ML3P8/trunk
```

And here's the deleted part:

```
/proj/SAM1/users/ssudi/
```

`/proj/SAM1/` preceded `users/` and then followed `ssudi`.